# What is the maximum length of a URL in mule?

Tags: mule

I'm using the http:outbound-endpoint. what is the maximum length of the address field?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the Mule HTTP transport XML schema nor the underlying `java.net.URI` impose a limit, so the true limit comes from the HTTP URL itself, which has been discussed in this SO question: [What is the maximum length of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/387927)